# Timer class - delay before executing function again?

Tags: function, timer, delay, counter, keyboard-events

I've got an issue that could be solved very easy, I think.. but not with my art brains. Google offers me Timer class, however not examples of what I need. 
Simply this is a vote counter - there are five buttons you can press, some of them will change first counter, others - second counter. Now what I want to do is to add a delay (like 3000 ms) before the function can be called again, so if the person starts smashing all the buttons rapidly, he won't spoil the results. 
Thanks for help

```
    var count:uint = 0;
    var count2:uint = 0;
    counter1.text = '0';
    counter2.text = '0';
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, Rescued)
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, Trapped)

    function Rescued(event:KeyboardEvent):void {    
if (event.keyCode == 49) 
count++;
counter1.text = count.toString();
if (event.keyCode == 109)
count++;
counter1.text = count.toString();
    }
    function Trapped(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
if (event.keyCode == 54)  
count2++;
counter2.text = count2.toString();
if (event.keyCode == 36)
count2++;
counter2.text = count2.toString();
if (event.keyCode == 189)
count2++;
counter2.text = count2.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using c++, I believe you can use the sleep() function and enter the number of milliseconds required in there.

Comment: Wow, that's my bad. I'm using AS3, and as far as I know there is no equivalent of sleep() from C++. Thanks, however

Comment: Here's a link to a page with some info about Time Delay in AS3.  I think the second chunk of code on there should be helpful for your purposes.
http://www.ilike2flash.com/2009/07/time-delay-in-actionscript-3.html